# How to apply missing security patches and do reboot server using shell script if missing security patches are found on AWS Linux AMI 1?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

**Problem:**
I do not want to use aws cli commands for applying patches and reboot AWS Linux Instances.
I have following command that can apply patches and reboot server every week.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update-minimal --sec-severity=critical,important --bugfix
sudo reboot
```

This script is working fine but I don't want to reboot server every week if missing security patches are not there.

Andhence,I tried to write following code but it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo yum update-minimal --sec-severity=critical,important --bugfix | grep "No Packages marked for minimal Update" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        sudo yum -y update-minimal --sec-severity=critical,important --bugfix > /dev/null
        sudo reboot
fi
```

Can anyone help with the script that can not reboot server if missing security patches are not found on the LinuxAMI1 server?

Comment: While your question is technically valid for StackOverflow (questions related to programming) you will probably have more success asking it on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/tour) (questions related to managing information technology systems) or [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) (questions related to Linux and Unix-like operating systems).

Comment: Edit your Q to show the output of your code when run with `set -x` after the first line. (Redirecting to `>/dev/null 2>&1` before you have a working project is usually premature optimization, maybe?) Good luck.